# Get the type from a nullable variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, types, nullable

```
public class MyType
{
    public int? MyId { get; set; }    
}

MyType myType = new MyType();
myType.MyId.GetType()
```

the last line returns an exception since `MyId` is not set (ie. it's null). How I get the type (`int?` or even `int`) in this case? Note, `int?` is used as an example, the variable may have any type, this is just a simplified example.

Note, according to Microsoft, this is supposed to work:

```
int? a = 17;
Type typeOfA = a.GetType();
Console.WriteLine(typeOfA.FullName);
// Output:
// System.Int32
```

and it does work when the value is assigned...

EDIT.

Looking at some of the replies and comments, I would like to add that in code, I pass myType.MyId as an object to a method that needs to figure out its type. Basically it looks similar to:

```
public void RunQuery(string sql, List<(string parameterName, object parameterValue)> parameters)
```

so myType.MyId is passed into RunQuery as parameterValue

Comment: `GetType()` gets the type of the entity stored in a variable, field or property.  If its null, there is no such entity.  In that case (*I think*) you would have to use reflection.  `typeof(MyType).GetProperty("MyId").PropertyType` should get you the property's type, which will be `Nullable<int>`.  You can pass that into `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type)` to get the underlying type inside the nullable.  For variables (again, *I think*) you could write a generic method to extract the inner type.

Answer (score 5):

You can use reflection to get declared type of a property (which is known at compile time):

```
Type t = typeof(MyType).GetProperty(nameof(MyType.MyId)).PropertyType;
```

And `GetType()` is used to figure out the actual type of an object in runtime, but that does not make sense for a `null` reference.

**Edit:**

When you cast `Nullable<T>` to an `Object`, its value is boxed, so, if it was `null`, you will get just an `Object` variable with `null` reference, and you won't be able to find out the type any more.

So, you should somehow change your infrastructure to make the type be passed with your parameter. The fastest workaround is to pass it explicitly

```
List<(string parameterName, object parameterValue, Type parameterType)> parameters
```

Check out [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter?view=netframework-4.7.2), I am not sure, but this is probably exactly what you need to use.

Comment: so since it's a generic method, I don't even have the information about the class MyType, i'm just passing myType.MyId as a parameter to another method

Comment: @user19754 then what is the type of this parameter?

Comment: it's passed as an object (object parameterValue), so then I can do parameterValue.GetType() to get the type for non-nullable types of parameterValueor for nullable types of parameterValue, where the value is not null. I get an exception when it's null.

Comment: @user19754 so, when someone passes null, then you have a local `object` variable with null value - there is no way to find out which type it could be

Comment: @user19754 try making your method generic like `Method<T>(T parameterValue)` and obtain your type like `Type type = typeof (T);`.

Answer (score 2):

[Edited], I've re-written my solution to address your question:  Making a function that is agnostic to MyType:

```
string GetPropertyName<T>(T prop)
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
    {
        return type.GenericTypeArguments[0].FullName;
    }
    else
    {
        return type.FullName;
    }
}
```

You can now call it like this:

```
MyType myType = new MyType();
string name = GetPropertyName(myType.MyId);
Console.WriteLine(name);  // Outputs System.Int32
```

I've test it, and it's working for me.

BTW, if you pass it a non-nullable member, it will return that property name.  You can test that for yourself.

Comment: I don't understand how it helps at all. I don't need to determine if it's a nullable type. In fact, I could just compare the value to null to "deduct" this. I need to know the underlying type as this is a parameter for a db query and i need to declare it with the correct db type.

Comment: Sorry to give you an incomplete solution.  Just added more.

Comment: @user19754, have you been able to try this solution?

Comment: In your code you imply the knowledge about MyType, however, in my case I don't know, myType.MyId is passed as an object parameter. I will edit the question to make it more specific

Comment: @user19754.  I've re-written my answer.  I'm not sure if that completely answers your updated question above, but perhaps it points you towards a solution.